# Hashtables and Class data

Tags: java

I have a problem that I am trying to solve. If anyone can point me to the right direction that would be nice. What I am doing is building a class called `Info` that holds nothing but data. Which is a String name, Token type, etc. This class is within another class called `SymbolTable`. This class adds data to a Hashtable which holds a name:key and the class `Info`:value.

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the data out of `Info` from the Hashtable value.
I tried doing a `toString` method but that just spit out raw data from the class `Info`.

Here is my code:

```
public class SymbolTable {
private Hashtable<String, Info> myTable = new Hashtable<String, Info>();


public void add(String name, IdInfoToken kind){
    Info valueInfo = new Info();
    valueInfo.symbol = name;
    valueInfo.tokenKind = kind;
    myTable.put(name, valueInfo);
}

public String toString(){
    String answer = " ";
    answer += myTable;
    return answer;
}


private class Info {
    String symbol;
    IdInfoToken tokenKind;     
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would retrieve the data in the same manner that you placed it in:  by the key.

I don't know what the value of `name` is which you pass in to your wrapping `add` method, but in essence, it would be something similar to this:

```
public Info retrieve(String name) {
    return myTable.get(name);
}
```

Further to this, unless you **really** need the synchronization, use a `Map<String, Info>` interface with a `HashMap` concrete implementation instead of `Hashtable`.  It's one of the things that the [Javadoc recommends at the bottom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Comment: I tried that but it only shows the Raw data in 'Info' class. This is what I get: Symbol Table{car=parser.SymbolTable$Info@29086036, bar=parser.SymbolTable$Info@64e48e45, foo=parser.SymbolTable$Info@593887c2}

Comment: That's `Info`'s internal `toString()` method.  I don't know if you're implementing that or if it's something else that's implementing that, but that output is coming from the fact that you're calling `System.out.println(info);`.  If it's a class you own, override `toString()` and give it meaning.  If it's not a class you own, extract meaning from it and print that instead of blindly calling `toString()`.

Comment: Hey Makoto, Thanks for the help. The Info Class I created which is listed in the code I provided. The class `Info` is inside the `HashTable`. So I can't just write `Info.toString()` and print the data. I can but what If I created `Info.getValue()`, how would I call this method when the class is inside the `Hashtable`?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the scope of `toString()`.  Yes, you can do *exactly* what you want to with `toString()`, but the catch is that you have to actually override the method to do it.  [Check out this particular trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) for a little more context.  Lastly, if your entity is inside of a data structure, you either are querying for it - at which point you can call whichever method you like, or you're storing it.